# Regular expression to exclude and capture an optional substring

Tags: regex

I've got this strings:

```
A. rest/asks/foo.bar.json
B. rest/asks/foo.bar
```

I need a regular expression that will allow me to capture following substrings:

```
1. 'rest'
2. 'asks'
3. '/foo.bar'(optional)
4. '.json' (optional)
```

I spent some hours searching the sollution but unfortunately didn't find the solution

Tried this:

```
^(rest)\/([^\/\.]+)(.+)?(?=(\.json))
```

But the `\.json` is required in this case

Results:

A. `rest/asks/foo.bar.json`

```
1.  [0-4]   `rest`
2.  [5-9]   `asks`
3.  [9-17]  `/foo.bar`
4.  [17-22] `.json`
```

B. `rest/asks/foo.bar`

```
Your pattern does not match the subject string.
```

Tried this:

```
^(rest)\/([^\/\.]+)(.+)?(?=(\.json)?)
```

Results:

A. `rest/asks/foo.bar.json`

```
1.  [0-4]   `rest`
2.  [5-9]   `asks`
3.  [9-17]  `/foo.bar.json`
```

B. `rest/asks/foo.bar`

```
1.  [0-4]   `rest`
2.  [5-9]   `asks`
3.  [9-17]  `/foo.bar`
```

Can anyone help me?

How can I make expression to matche substrings like I need?

You can test regular expression here: http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- use an OR statement to have `$` or `.json` at the end: `(?=$|(\.json))`
- make your pattern catching "foo.bar" non-greedy: `(.+?)?`, to not catch `.json`

```
^(rest)\/([^\/\.]+)(.+?)?(?=$|(\.json))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: It works men! Thanks a lot! Where did you generated the diagram?

Answer (score 2):

Your first regex is good, but you forget 1 thing : You may finish without the .json :

For this you have to say you can have .json OR end of the line $ : `(?=$|(\.json))`

Then you have : `^(rest)\/([^\/\.]+)(.+?)?(?=$|(\.json))`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qN6bV9/1) (Look at the right panel on match information)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go for positive lookahead. `(.*?)(\.json)?`  would capture the characters before the `\.json` to an optional group and capture `.json` into another optional group.

```
^(rest)\/([^\/\.]+)(.*?)(\.json)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bR6fI0/4)

Comment: It's good, but you need to change something - change `(?:(.+?)(\.json)?)`  into (?:(.+?)(\.json)?)?` to make it optional. It will not work properly for `rest/asks` if not.